How to color the specific region?
I am drawing the graph below, and I would like to color a specific region. It's somewhat similar to what I asked last time How to color a specific internal region?, but with some differences. I'm unsure how to describe or piece together the region I want to color.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{whitenode/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, minimum size=1pt,inner sep=8pt}}
   \tikzset{whitenode2/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, minimum size=1pt,inner sep=2pt}}
    \draw[thick] (0, 0) ellipse (5cm and 3cm);

    \foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
        \node[whitenode] (v\i) at ({5*cos(360/11*\i)}, {3*sin(360/11*\i)}) {$\i$};
    }

    \node[whitenode2, above right, xshift=-90pt, yshift=-5pt](s') at (v4) {\small $s'$};
     \node[whitenode2, above right, xshift=-100pt, yshift=-50pt](t') at (v4) {\small $t'$};
     
       \draw[thick,bend left=-110,looseness=1.25] (v1) to (t');
       \draw[thick,bend left=90,looseness=1.25] (v8) to (s');
% \scoped[on background layer]{
%     \draw[fill=red!20,bend left=-110,looseness=1.25] (v1) to (t');
%      \draw[thick,fill=red!20,bend left=90,looseness=1.25] (v8) to (s');}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}


The graph below is the one I wanted (for now, using Inkscape).

I originally planned to use the method mentioned last time by the samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, adding the following code, but the result is as shown below
 \scoped[on background layer]{
     \draw[fill=red!20,bend left=-110,looseness=1.25] (v1) to (t');
      \draw[thick,fill=red!20,bend left=90,looseness=1.25] (v8) to (s');}



Common tools for these kinds of problems are intersections and the spath3 library. The former is used by the latter to find the intersection of the left-bended curves. Then, with spath/remove components the little bits are removed from the saved path so that they can later joined with the arc.
This leads to one continous closed path.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, spath3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  whitenode/.style={draw, fill=white, shape=circle, inner sep=8pt},
  whitenode2/.style={whitenode, inner sep=2pt},
  x radius=5, y radius=3, looseness=1.25
]
\draw[thick] (0, 0) ellipse[];

\foreach \i in {0,...,10}
  \node[whitenode] (v\i) at (360/11*\i:5 and 3) {$\i$};

\node[whitenode2, above right, xshift=-90pt, yshift=-5pt]
  (s') at (v4) {\small $s'$};
\node[whitenode2, above right, xshift=-100pt, yshift=-50pt]
  (t') at (v4) {\small $t'$};

\draw[thick, bend left=-110] (v1) to (t') [spath/save=v1t];
\draw[thick, bend left=  90] (v8) to (s') [spath/save=v8s];

\scoped[
  on background layer,
  spath/split at intersections={v1t}{v8s},
  spath/remove components={v1t}{2},
  spath/remove components={v8s}{2}]
\fill[red!20]
  (v8) arc[start angle=360/11*8, end angle=360/11]
  -- (spath cs:{v1t} 0) [spath/use={v1t, weld}]
                        [spath/use={v8s, reverse, weld}]
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


Nice. If I do not use spath3, may I have some other ways to do that. I need to draw many figures like that, and I will learn spath3 in some weeks.

@licheng The fillbetween library of PGFPlots has similar functionality. You can also fill the big ellipse with white and then use a similar approach like yours to fill the area behind it with red by combining the bended paths and adding a few corrections to it.

Indeed, it seems good. Thank you.
